# Dynamically Assign tabindex using a function by passing current div classname

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

```
<div class=".btn-assigned" tabindex={{getTabIndex(e)}}>

getTabIndex(e)
{

if(e.target.class==".class-disabled")
{
return 0;
}
else
{
return -1;
}

}
```

I want to add tabindex automatically to a div according to current class name. but i am unable to do it as a function.

Comment: are you using any library ?

Comment: @Aravind: no libraries